# Working on each frame from a Vimba camera

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, camera

I am working with an Allied Vision Vimba camera to monitor an experiment involving a laser.

I have written a code that allows me to take one frame from the camera live imaging (displayed in `pictureBoxLiveCamera`, in black and white), put it in another PictureBox (`pictureBoxFixe1`) and work on it. The code works fine for the most part, even though it is not finished.
My problem is that, eventually, I will need to work continuously, meaning on every frame from the camera (about 15-20 per second), and I am starting to feel like this is going to be complicated.

I am not asking you to help me through the whole process, but I have a precise exemple of something that is not working and I would like to understand. I am working with the Vimba .NET API, so some of the functions called might not be familiar to most of you (and they are not much more to me, really), but I'll try my best to explain them in the code (the API manual is kinda cryptic).

My code has a part that, when I isolate one frame from the camera to work on it (via a `button-click`event, draws an histogram that graphs the number of pixels on the vertical axis and digital number value on the horizontal axis. This way I know if some of the pixels are saturated (at 255), and I can lower the exposure time. This works fine, here is the code for the button that isolate one frame and draws the histogram :

```
private void fixButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_Acquiring == true) //mm_Acquiring being true indicates that the camera is sending images continuously, and that they are toggled in pictureBoxLiveCamera
        {
            pictureBoxFixe1.Image = SaveBitmap; //SaveBitmap is the bitmap isolated from the live camera in an earlier code portion

            Array.Clear(PixelColorCount, 0, 256);
            foreach (var Series in chartHist.Series)
            {
                Series.Points.Clear();
            }

            //Creating a bitmap from pictureBoxFixe1 to draw the histogram from
            Bitmap Couleur = new Bitmap(pictureBoxFixe1.Image);

            //Collecting data from pictureBoxFixe1
            for (int i = 0; i < 1023; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 157; j < 288; j++)
                {
                    PixelColorCount[Couleur.GetPixel(i + 1, j).B] += 1;
                }

                for (int j = 484; j < 615; j++)
                {
                    PixelColorCount[Couleur.GetPixel(i + 1, j).B] += 1;
                }
            }

            //Plotting the pixel counter, to detect saturation
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                chartHist.Series["Pixel count"].Points.AddXY(i, PixelColorCount[i]);
            }

            //If there are saturated pixels : toggle a title on chart 1 to warn the user
            if (PixelColorCount[255] > 1)
            {
                chartHist.Titles["Title1"].Visible = false;
                chartHist.Titles["Title2"].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chartHist.Titles["Title1"].Visible = true;
                chartHist.Titles["Title2"].Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Acquisition is not running.", "Something went wrong !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Now what I want is to make this work live, with every frame incoming from the camera. But it doesn't work and I can't find why. Here is what I tried :

```
private void BtAcquisitionLiveCam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here is the part of the code that starts the live acquisition when I click the button, I don't copy it completely because I don't think this is relevant.
    this.m_Acquiring = true;
    mycamera.OnFrameReceived += new Camera.OnFrameReceivedHandler(this.OnFrameReceived); //This is the event handler for the reception of a frame for the camera, it is part of the Vimba API
    mycamera.StartContinuousImageAcquisition(1); //According to the manual, this "Starts streaming and allocates the needed frames", with the argument being "count of Frame(s) which should be used for this method"
}

private void OnFrameReceived(Frame frame) //Frame is the class in which the code puts the data from the camera, frame is the last pack of data received from the camera
{
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    if (true == m_Acquiring)
    {
        try
        {
            mycamera.QueueFrame(frame);
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Frame queuing failed.", "Something went wrong !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Acquisition is not running.", "Something went wrong !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }

    featureExposureTime.FloatValue = (double)hScrollBarLiveExposureTime.Value;
    frame.Fill(ref myBitmap);
    pictureBoxLiveCamera.Image = myBitmap;
    SaveBitmap = myBitmap; //Up until here the code works perfectly, because I can use SaveBitmap without problem later in the code (not shown here)

    Array.Clear(PixelColorCount, 0, 256);
    foreach (var Series in chartHist.Series)
    {
        Series.Points.Clear();
    }

    //Collecting data from pictureBoxFixe1
    for (int i = 1; i < 1023; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 767; j++)
        {
            PixelColorCount[SaveBitmap.GetPixel(i, j).B] += 1;
        }
    }

    //Plotting the pixel counter, to detect saturation
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        chartHist.Series["Pixel count"].Points.AddXY(i, PixelColorCount[i]);
    }

    //If there are saturated pixels : toggle a title on chart 1 to warn the user
    if (PixelColorCount[255] > 1)
    {
        chartInit.Titles["Title1"].Visible = true;
    }
    else { }
}
```

Sorry for the amount of code, but I thought I couldn't do otherwise. My problem is that the histogram doesn't show at all (well it is set as Visible, I see the title, but nothing gets plotted in it). Does anyone have any idea ?

The thing that is driving me crazy is that the VimbaViewer program that's provided with the camera does exactly what I want in a flawless way, but I don't have access to it's source code...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly, your OnFrameReceived event is firing correctly, but the WinForm application UI is not updating after each frame is processed.

It appears that "chartInit" is being referenced in your OnFrameReceived instead of "chartHist", is that supposed to be the case?

Whatever your chart control is, try "chart.Refresh()" or "chart.Update()". It might not be updating the UI thread from the event loop.

Another thing you'll need to think about is how fast these images are coming in. Will it draw and redraw the chart 15-20 times per second? Is that reasonable? Might need some sort of queue/averaging mechanism to only update the chart every x seconds, or perhaps if some threshold value is exceeded with respect to change in the images. Just a thought.